# How can I give a Space a custom name?

Tags: terminal, macos, spaces, customization

I'd like to give my Spaces helpful names like "Graphics" and "Communications" instead of using confusing, generic names like Desktop 1 and Desktop 2. Is there a way to accomplish that through a setting, a Terminal/hidden command, or a third party application? I'm using Mavericks.

Comment: By spaces do you mean Mission Control on Mavericks? The old functionality where you could name virtual screens and they would exist in a semi-permanent grid is no longer shipping with OS X.

Comment: Yes. I am okay with all the functionality in Mavericks, though. I just want to be able to assign names. If it's not officially supported, I'm looking for something I can enter into Terminal, a plist to edit, or some other trick that will let me name them.

Answer (score 1):

The third-party program [TotalSpaces2](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com) seems to offer this feature, along with many other Spaces-related features.